# No positive integer solutions $(x, y, z)$ to the diophantine equation $2x^6+3y^6=z^3$

Tags: number-theory, exponential-diophantine-equations

Can someone please check if I provided a correct and adequate proof to the following:

There are no positive integer solutions $(x, y, z)$ to the equation $$2x^6+3y^6=z^3 \tag{1}$$.

Here's how I approached the problem:

First suppose $(x, y, z)$ is a solution to $(1)$ and the $gcd(x, y, z) = d$, which means that $x=dx_1, y=dy_1, z=dz_1$, where $gcd(x_1, y_1, z_1) = 1$ and $d$ is an integer.

Substituting in and rearranging we get $$d^3(2x_1^6+3y_1^6)=z_1^3.$$

Upon dividing both sides by $d^3$ we obtain $$2x_1^6+3y_1^6=k^3,$$ where $k$ represents the quotient of $z_1$ and $d$.

We have obtained an equation very similar to $(1)$ with a "smaller" solution $(x_1, y_1, k)$, which yields a contradiction by Fermat's method of infinite descent.

Thus we have proven the statement.

Suggestions of all sorts are much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: You can use your method to prove that $x^2+y^2=z^2$ has no positive integer solutions

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: "First suppose that $(x,y,z)$ is a solution to $x^2+y^2=z^2$ and the $\gcd(x,y,z)=d$, which means$x=dx_1$, $y=dy_1$, $z=dz_1$. Substituting and dividing both sides by $d^2$, we get $x_1^2+y_1^2=z_1^2$, which is a "smaller" solution, which yields a contradiction by Fermat's method of infinite descent." -- And yet $(3,4,5)$ is a positive solution to $x^2+y^2=z^2$. You may want to revisit your method.

Comment: Fermat's method of infinite descent is the following: there is no $f:X \to X$ for which $\forall x \in X\, f(x)<x$, where $X$ is a poset satisfying the descending chain condition (for example, the poset of solutions to the OP's equation with the lexicographical order). Dividing by the gcd does not give a function with the required condition, since it is idempotent.

Comment: So am I better off using modular arithmetic?

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in several question comments, e.g., this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3708831/no-positive-integer-solutions-x-y-z-to-the-diophantine-equation-2x63y6/3708847#comment7622270_3708831), the main issue with your proof is that if $d = 1$, then your final equation is the same as the first. You haven't proven that $d \gt 1$. To show this, consider the equation modulo $7$. By [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), if $7 \not\mid n$, then $n^6 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$. This means $x^6$ and $y^6$ can only be congruent to $0$ or $1$ modulo $7$, so $2x^6 + 3y^6$ can only be congruent to $0$, $2$, $3$ or $5$ modulo $7$.

However, $z^3 \pmod{7}$ is equivalent to only one of $0$, $1$ or $6$. The only match with the LHS is when it's $0$, which means $x$, $y$ and $z$ must all be a multiple of $7$. Thus, you have $7 \mid d$, so $d \gt 1$ and then your argument of infinite descent will work. I'll leave it to you to update your proof accordingly.